# rails production migration error - undefined method `-@' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I just faced with problem when my migration with custom sql works fine on development environment and failed on production.

My migration looks like this:

```
class DbPatch < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute("START TRANSACTION")
    execute("update users set status = 1 where status = 3")
    execute("COMMIT")
  end

  def down
    execute("START TRANSACTION")
    execute("update users set status = 3 where status = 1")
    execute("COMMIT")
  end
end
```

And on production env migration failed with next error message:

```
== 20140627155848 DbPatch: migrating =================================
-- execute("START TRANSACTION")
   -> 0.0001s
-- execute("update users set status = 1 where status = 3")
   -> 0.0003s

rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `-@' for nil:NilClass/var/www/app/releases/20140628083752/db/migrate/20140627155848_db_patch.rb:4:in `up'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:598:in `exec_migration'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:579:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:578:in `block in migrate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:294:in `with_connection'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:577:in `migrate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:752:in `migrate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:994:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1042:in `ddl_transaction'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:993:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:954:in `block in migrate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `each'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:950:in `migrate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:808:in `up'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/migration.rb:785:in `migrate'
/var/www/app/shared/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.0/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:34:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

After an half hour of research in ActiveRecord sources I recognized that problem was in my custom 'START TRANSACTION'.

It looks like rails automatically execute all migrations on production environment in transaction.

So the next code works correct:

```
class DbPatch < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute("update users set status = 1 where status = 3")
  end

  def down
    execute("update users set status = 3 where status = 1")
  end
end
```

I'm posting this topic here to keep knowledges not only in my head :)